# PHP - Creating image with imagettftext with Greek text

Tags: php, internationalization, imagettftext

I'm trying to use imagettftext to create an image using this Greek text "από τον/την".

This text is read from a MySQL database table from a field whose collation is set to utf8-unicode-ci.

The text comes out of the database as "Î±Ï€ÏŒ Ï„Î¿Î½/Ï„Î·Î½".

Here's the code (lifted from php.net)

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = html_entity_decode('Î±Ï€ÏŒ Ï„Î¿Î½/Ï„Î·Î½', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');

// Replace path by your own font path
$font = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.localhost/libs/fonts/CustomFont.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

This produces an image with "Î±Ï€ÏŒ Ï„Î¿Î½/Ï„Î·Î½" and not "από τον/την".

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it directly from the database?

Comment: Yes, when reading from the database, it comes out as this string "Î±Ï€ÏŒ Ï„Î¿Î½/Ï„Î·Î½", which is what I plugged into html_entity_decode

Comment: I mean without printing it out, browsers/os's can screw up encoding sometimes.

Comment: Oh right. When I do $text = "από τον/την" in the code, it comes out right. The problem is that I need to read it from the DB. Thanks!

Comment: What I'm saying is when you print it out from the database your local encoding on yoru OS/browser could make it come out wrong. Have you tried it **directly** from the database?

Answer (score 1):

Use other fonts like

```
$font = 'arial.ttf';
```

and it works just fine