# write greek characters with php

Tags: php, imagettftext, gdlib

I'm writing Greek characters on an image file using GD library. [imagettftext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)

```
$font = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/fonts/greek.ttf';
$top = '125'; 
$left='120'; 
$color = imagecolorallocate($outputImage, 0, 0, 0);
imagettftext($outputImage, 40, 0, $left, $top, $color, $font, 'Δ Γ Δ Γ');
```

[image]

So, my question is which fonts should i use here, or anything else causing this ? I even tried `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` within the function which generated the image.

Reference :

1. Font i have used above is http://www.dafont.com/ancient-geek.font
2. http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/greek.html
3. http://www.greece.com/info/language/greek_alphabet/ [The first columns letters are the letters i need to print]

Comment: I didn't quite understand your problem. Is it that you can't print the specific font? Have you tried printing something else?

Comment: @Tony i'm trying to write 'Δ Γ Δ Γ' this on the image, other general alphabet characters gets easily printed.

Comment: I am from Greece, can you please try to print those 'Δ Γ Δ Γ' ? EDIT : Have you tried another font of greek letters?

Comment: Hi @Tony when i try to print those i get the rectangular boxes like in the picture above.

Comment: I got the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416546/php-creating-image-with-imagettftext-with-greek-text?rq=1 it's printable using arial.ttf fonts.

Comment: http://www.dafont.com/ancient-geek.font is not a UTF-8 font. In fact if you're using Unicode you don't need a special font as Unicode already supports greek characters (and probably includes ancient greek). Just use one of the existing unicode fonts.

Comment: @apokryfos ok, thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php):

> If a character is used in the string which is not supported by the font, a hollow rectangle will replace the character.

So it seems, that:

1. Your font doesn't support Greek characters (that's strange);
2. The path to the font can be wrong... Try with hardcoded path, and check that the file is available;
3. Your source file can be not in UTF-8, so check the source file encoding.

Comment: It's possible the font is an ISO-8859-7 font so it won't map correctly to Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

It surprisingly worked with `arial.ttf` font.

Reference : [PHP - Creating image with imagettftext with Greek text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416546/php-creating-image-with-imagettftext-with-greek-text?rq=1)